# WCF services endpoint binding behind load balancer

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services

i have a WCF web service with basic http bindings. i am using https but the SSL is handled by load balancer so the end traffic will be http when it gets to wcf services. but my endpoint would be the virtual ip of the load balancer.

The question i have is when i try to add this reference to call this service i add it as https:///service.svc?wsdl but it comes back saying the wsdl is  invalid. do i need to change my endpoint in web.config to be loadbalancer ip? or there is more than that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to Enable both Http and Https to get it to work the dsco file kept trying to download as http.

Answer (score 0):

I would try changing the endpoint to the ip of the load balancer.

Comment: that did not help, when i try to pull wsdl, it tries to pull it from serever ip instead of load balancer